# Why there is a unsubscribe from product in a product stock alert e-mail?

Tags: product, ce-1.9.0.1, cron, email-reminders, alert

A product stock alert is a "single e-mail sent" notification.

Nevertheless, I wonder why in the e-mail message there is a link to unsubscribe from the product, although the record in `product_alert_stock` is already flagged when the e-mail is sent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[EDIT]**
I missed the link for unsubscribing from one single product.
You are right, it does not make any sense at all.
The only difference I found is that, when an e-mail is sent with a stock alert, it is marked as `sent` in the database.
When you click to unsubscribe from one product stock alert, the record is deleted from the database.

But the effect is the same. You never get the same e-mail again unless you subscribe again for the stock alert and the product goes back in stock the second time.

**Initial answer**
Here is a scenario where this is valid.
You subscribe to the stock alert for 2 products. Let's call them A & B.

Then one night A goes back to stock.
You receive the e-mail that A is back in stock.

You click on the link `Unsubscribe from all stock alerts`.
You are unsubscribed from ALL stock alerts.

Next night, B comes back in stock.
You are NOT notified about this because you unsubscribed.

Comment: Well, there are 2 links on the product alert e-mail, and I referred to the first, the one that says: unsubscribe from this product.... The other link is the one you posted about, that one is fine.

Comment: @Niloct. yeah, I missed that. You are absolutely right. This makes no sense. at all. I will edit the answer.