# Product stock alert - sent only once without unsubscribing

Tags: magento-1.9, product, email, stock, alert

Why the Product Stock Alert / Notification is sent only once even when customer won't unsubscribe from product's alert?

Example situation:
Customer subscribe to receive notification about Product A and Product B.

Both comes into stock, he receives email alert as it should be.

Now product A is going out of stock again.

After a week Product A comes back to in stock.

Theoretically - **customer should receive notification** - he didn't unsubscribe from that product's alert.

While in the real world if the customer wants the notification he has to **subscribe to the product again** - why?

Considering that the table `product_alert_stock` has a column called `send_count` - which's counting the emails sent but only if the customer subscribes second time.

If this is a feature not a bug, what's the point of **Unsubscribing from specific product alert**?

P.S. I know about: [Why there is a unsubscribe from product in a product stock alert e-mail?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29654/why-there-is-a-unsubscribe-from-product-in-a-product-stock-alert-e-mail) but this not straight answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **E-commerce business,product stock subscription** one of subscription where customer ***will get once time notification*** on once  and it is totally ***differ from newsletter subscription***.

In magento,a custom stock notification is maintain by field  `status`  of table `product_alert_stoct`.

When a customer will subscribe  a product for stock notification,***it value becomes 0 that mean it mail  is not yet sended*** .

Whenever that product stock is come and mail sended it value `become 1` that means and  ***customer will automatically unsubscripted from this product stock list***.

If same product ***becomes  out of stock*** and ***same customer will again subscribe for stock notification*** then it `status` value `becomes to 0` and `send_count` value `increase to 2` .

And when magento is fire out of stock notification mail  it takes those records of  the table `product_alert_stock` whose `column value  status is 0 and product status is in stock`

Comment: Thank you very much for claryfiying few things. 
I still don't understand what's the point of unsubscribe from specific product inside email template when it's automatically unsubscribed after receiving that email?

Comment: whenever magento is send of out of stock notification mail to customer using cron job that times the send field value change to 1 automcatically

Comment: Indeed - automatically inside Observer.php around line 258.
IMHO it's solved in really not-friendly way. Sending unsubcribe link in default which's basically **useless** because the customer already has been unsubscribed automatically. 
However it's pretty easy to extend so I'll proceed with my own solution for this. Will wait with accepting for someone who maybe can answer the question in more theoretically way (some Magento dev's?).